# Can I install a custom rom with SIM Lock enabled?

Tags: sim-card

I purchased a phone for development purposes knowing that it was being sold for parts/repair. The phone can't read SIM cards for some reason and the battery always says 999%. No idea why, but everything else is fully functional.

When I go to Location & Security > SIM Card Lock its enabled. I cant unlock it because I dont know the PIN.

If I were to root the phone and install CM7 -- would the phone ask me to input this PIN after I install it?